# Include jquery library in PartialView which is not _Layout inherited

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a PartialView which is not inherited under _Layout. I want to include the jquery validate library. I am doing it directly inside the Partialview.cshtml with the script tag which works but I am not sure if this is correct. Because I have many partial views that are not inherited under _Layout , is there a way to include this library with out the  tag in each .cshtml and in somehow automated way ?

In each single cshtml partial view I do:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Title";
}

<script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Partial.cshtml**

```
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Title";
    }

    ... CODE ...

    @section Scripts{
           <script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    }
```

and at the end of

**_Layout.cshtml** add `@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)`

Comment: But my partial views do not have any inheritance from _Layout. What Is the point of @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

Comment: You await the loading of the scripts